# How to add the results of chi-square calculations and Fisher's exact test to the table in R

Tags: r

Let's take reproducible example from last my question

```
AE=structure(list(TRTGROUP_E1_C18 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), AETERM = c("increase in lymphocytes", "increase in lymphocytes", 
"increase in abs. lymphocytes", "increase in lymphocytes", "decrease in abs. neutrophils", 
"decrease in neutrophils", "decrease in abs. monocytes", "decrease in monocytes", 
"increase in lymphocytes", "decrease in hemoglobin", "decrease in neutrophils", 
"decrease in abs. monocytes ")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

I can build frequency tables as I was told.

```
library(table1)

table1(~AETERM | TRTGROUP_E1_C18, data = AE) This is good format.
```

However, now I need to calculate the p-value between treatment groups(TRTGROUP_E1_C18) for adverse events. For each AE, I can calculate using  simple commands `fisher.test()` or `chisq.test()`, but it's cumbersome and inconvenient. That is. First, for example, I need to calculate the statistics between groups for `decrease abs.monocytes`, then dy `decrease in abs. neutrophils` and so on, the list of AEs can be overwhelming. How to make these stat tests were calculated for all AEs between groups at once, so that for each AE, I do not write a separate line manually and copy the result to a table? And how to make 2 columns appear when generating a table (a very convenient format for me), one with the chi-square calculation, and the other with Fisher's exact test.
Like this desired result.

[image]

Any help is very important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the Chi-squared and Fisher tests of all pairs of values in `AETERM`, then the best way would probably be to write a function to do that.  Here's what I would suggest.  This makes the original table and produces the relevant tests for all pairs of values.

```r
AE=structure(list(TRTGROUP_E1_C18 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                      1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                  AETERM = c("increase in lymphocytes", "increase in lymphocytes", 
                            "increase in abs. lymphocytes", "increase in lymphocytes", "decrease in abs. neutrophils", 
                            "decrease in neutrophils", "decrease in abs. monocytes", "decrease in monocytes", 
                            "increase in lymphocytes", "decrease in hemoglobin", "decrease in neutrophils", 
                            "decrease in abs. monocytes")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                 -12L))

library(table1)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'table1'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     units, units<-
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union


y <- "AETERM"
x <- "TRTGROUP_E1_C18"
test_combs <- function(x, y, data, ...){
  xvals <- data[[x]]
  yvals <- data[[y]]
  form <- as.formula(paste0("~", y, " | ", x))
  tab <- table1(form, data=data)
  uny <- unique(yvals)
  combs <- combn(length(uny), 2)
  l <- lapply(1:ncol(combs), function(i){
    ind <- which(yvals %in% c(uny[combs[1,i]], uny[combs[2,i]]))
    if(sd(xvals[ind]) != 0 & !is.na(sd(xvals[ind]))){
      x2 <- chisq.test(table(xvals[ind], yvals[ind]))[c("estimate", "p.value")]
      f <- fisher.test(table(xvals[ind], yvals[ind]))[c("estimate", "p.value")]
      x2 <- sapply(x2, function(x)ifelse(is.null(x), NA, x))
      f <- sapply(f, function(x)ifelse(is.null(x), NA, x))
      tibble(lev1 = uny[combs[1,i]], 
                 lev2 = uny[combs[2,i]], 
                 X2_stat = x2[1], 
                 x2_pval = x2[2], 
                 Fisher_stat = f[1], 
                 Fisher_pval = f[2])
    }else{
      tibble(lev1 = uny[combs[1,i]], 
                 lev2 = uny[combs[2,i]], 
                 X2_stat = NA, 
                 x2_pval = NA, 
                 Fisher_stat = NA, 
                 Fisher_pval = NA)
    }
  })
  return(list(table = tab, 
         tests = as.data.frame(bind_rows(l))))
  
}
test_combs("TRTGROUP_E1_C18", "AETERM", AE)
#> $table
#> 
#> $tests
#>                            lev1                         lev2 X2_stat  x2_pval
#> 1       increase in lymphocytes increase in abs. lymphocytes      NA 1.000000
#> 2       increase in lymphocytes decrease in abs. neutrophils      NA 1.000000
#> 3       increase in lymphocytes      decrease in neutrophils      NA 1.000000
#> 4       increase in lymphocytes   decrease in abs. monocytes      NA 1.000000
#> 5       increase in lymphocytes        decrease in monocytes      NA 1.000000
#> 6       increase in lymphocytes       decrease in hemoglobin      NA 0.819477
#> 7  increase in abs. lymphocytes decrease in abs. neutrophils      NA       NA
#> 8  increase in abs. lymphocytes      decrease in neutrophils      NA 1.000000
#> 9  increase in abs. lymphocytes   decrease in abs. monocytes      NA 1.000000
#> 10 increase in abs. lymphocytes        decrease in monocytes      NA       NA
#> 11 increase in abs. lymphocytes       decrease in hemoglobin      NA 1.000000
#> 12 decrease in abs. neutrophils      decrease in neutrophils      NA 1.000000
#> 13 decrease in abs. neutrophils   decrease in abs. monocytes      NA 1.000000
#> 14 decrease in abs. neutrophils        decrease in monocytes      NA       NA
#> 15 decrease in abs. neutrophils       decrease in hemoglobin      NA 1.000000
#> 16      decrease in neutrophils   decrease in abs. monocytes      NA 1.000000
#> 17      decrease in neutrophils        decrease in monocytes      NA 1.000000
#> 18      decrease in neutrophils       decrease in hemoglobin      NA 1.000000
#> 19   decrease in abs. monocytes        decrease in monocytes      NA 1.000000
#> 20   decrease in abs. monocytes       decrease in hemoglobin      NA 1.000000
#> 21        decrease in monocytes       decrease in hemoglobin      NA 1.000000
#>    Fisher_stat Fisher_pval
#> 1          Inf         1.0
#> 2          Inf         1.0
#> 3     0.408248         1.0
#> 4     0.408248         1.0
#> 5          Inf         1.0
#> 6     0.000000         0.4
#> 7           NA          NA
#> 8     0.000000         1.0
#> 9     0.000000         1.0
#> 10          NA          NA
#> 11    0.000000         1.0
#> 12         Inf         1.0
#> 13    0.000000         1.0
#> 14          NA          NA
#> 15         Inf         1.0
#> 16    1.000000         1.0
#> 17         Inf         1.0
#> 18    0.000000         1.0
#> 19    0.000000         1.0
#> 20         Inf         1.0
#> 21    0.000000         1.0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>